# Gesture detector for a container with stack

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a `stack` as child of `Gesture Detector`. Inside the stack I've 3 widgets:

1. Container with white background -----> bottom of stack
2. CustomPaint
3. image(PNG with transparent background) ----> top of the stack

The idea is I'll paint the bottom layer which is the container with background color of white so that the selected image will remain intact with its back outlines. Now my Gesture detector is needed for only the container with white background.

Here's my code:

```
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 4,
                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                    child: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onPanUpdate: (details) {
                          setState(() {
                            RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
                            points.add(TouchPoints(
                                points: renderBox
                                    .globalToLocal(details.globalPosition),
                                paint: Paint()
                                  ..strokeCap = strokeType
                                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                                  ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                                  ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
                          });
                        },
                        onPanStart: (details) {
                          setState(() {
                            RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
                            points.add(TouchPoints(
                                points: renderBox
                                    .globalToLocal(details.globalPosition),
                                paint: Paint()
                                  ..strokeCap = strokeType
                                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                                  ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                                  ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
                          });
                        },
                        onPanEnd: (details) {
                          setState(() {
                            points.add(null);
                          });
                        },
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            CustomPaint(
                              size: Size.infinite,
                              painter: MyPainter(pointsList: points),
                            ),
                            displayImage(context, widget.imagePath),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.brown,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                      child: displayMenu(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And here is a visual representation:
[image]

I tried putting the `Gesture Detector` widget like below:

```
Container(
   child: GestureDetector(.........),
   color: Colors.white,
),
```

to no avail.

Any suggestions about it and how to color only the bottom layer of the stack?

**Update 1:**

```
Container(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (details) {
                        setState(() {
                          RenderBox renderBox =
                              context.findRenderObject();
                          points.add(TouchPoints(
                              points: renderBox.globalToLocal(
                                  details.globalPosition),
                              paint: Paint()
                                ..strokeCap = strokeType
                                ..isAntiAlias = true
                                ..color =
                                    selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                                ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
                        });
                      },
                      onPanStart: (details) {
                        setState(() {
                          RenderBox renderBox =
                              context.findRenderObject();
                          points.add(TouchPoints(
                              points: renderBox.globalToLocal(
                                  details.globalPosition),
                              paint: Paint()
                                ..strokeCap = strokeType
                                ..isAntiAlias = true
                                ..color =
                                    selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                                ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
                        });
                      },
                      onPanEnd: (details) {
                        setState(() {
                          points.add(null);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
```

**Update 2:**

```
                      child: Container(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CustomPaint(
                                size: Size.infinite,
                                painter: MyPainter(pointsList: points),
                              ),
                              IgnorePointer(
                                ignoring: true,
                                child:
                                    displayImage(context, widget.imagePath),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

**Update 3:** On request I'm providing the image that show's color that get's out of the container

[image]

Comment: How about putting a white background for the image widget, so that the image is no longer transparent. So the drawing is not visible through the empty areas of the image?

Comment: @jigar Patel already implemented in my code. Please check it

Comment: have you tried to put the GestureDetector as a parent (not child) of the "white" Container?

Comment: @camillo777 so basically make GestureDetector the parent of "white" container and not the entire stack?

Comment: I've updated my code with the suggestions. Still don't work. As a matter of fact I cant draw anything

Comment: Hello @FahimHoque, I do not understand why you want the GestureDetector only on one layer of the stack? What is the purpose? Gesture Detector only detects the point, then you can decide to draw on the layer you prefer...

Comment: I've asked two questions. The gesture detector should only work for left container which has the image. It works all around and second problem is that I want to color the color layer(the one with white background) so the image itself doesn't get colored

Comment: @FahimHoque to me your code is working ok, can you post a wrong and correct image?

Comment: @camillo777 there's no correct image to provide but I'll provide link from which I got motivation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQwSPic_TzA
I've updated my code with the image

Comment: @camillo777 This comment is getting bigger. Shall we move to chat?

Answer (score 0):

If my guessing is right, the stack allow hittest to its top most widget with that constraints. So, Can you wrap IgnorePointer widget to the other children expect the container with white background widget abd try?

Comment: I have only two other widgets and ignore pointer takes only one child

Comment: Are you facing the issue yet after these changes?

Comment: yeah still the same. My colors are getting out of container and I still cant color the "White layer" background in the stack

Answer (score 0):

this code can help you a little bit to avoid drawing outside of the container; I have simplified the code a little bit, you can copy/paste it into DartPad to see it in action. Unfortunately I could not find a real transparent image on internet to make it work in DartPad too.

The idea is to check with the bound of the RenderBox to see if the point is inside or outside of the box to avoid to add it to the Points list:

> if (renderBox.paintBounds.contains(details.localPosition))

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<TouchPoints> points = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build MyAppState");
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.75,
                      width: constraints.maxWidth / 2,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          /*CustomPaint(
                              size: Size.infinite,
                              painter: MyPainter(points),
                            ),*/
                          //displayImage(context, widget.imagePath),
                          //Image.network("https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/glass-plate-on-transparent-background-vector-id915049220?s=612x612"),
                          Positioned.fill(
                            child: MyGesture(points),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  
                  Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.brown,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.75,
                      width: constraints.maxWidth / 2,
                      child: Text("menu"), //displayMenu(),
                    ),
                  
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyGesture extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<TouchPoints> points;

  MyGesture(this.points);

  State<MyGesture> createState() => MyGestureState();
}

class MyGestureState extends State<MyGesture> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //print("build MyGestureState");
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          setState(() {
            RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            if (renderBox.paintBounds.contains(details.localPosition))             {

            widget.points.add(TouchPoints(
                details.localPosition,
                Paint()
                  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                  ..color = Colors.red
                  ..strokeWidth = 0.1));
            }
          });
        },
        onPanStart: (details) {
          print("onPanStart");
          setState(() {
            //RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            widget.points.add(TouchPoints(
                details.localPosition,
                Paint()
                  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                  ..color = Colors.green
                  ..strokeWidth = 0.1));
          });
        },
        onPanEnd: (details) {
          setState(() {
            //widget.points.add(null);
          });
        },
        child:
          
            CustomPaint(
          size: Size.infinite,
          painter: MyPainter(widget.points),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<TouchPoints> pointsList;

  MyPainter(this.pointsList);

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (TouchPoints point in pointsList) {
      canvas.drawCircle(point.points, 5, point.paint);
    }
  }

  bool shouldRepaint(MyPainter old) => true;
}

class TouchPoints {
  Offset points;
  Paint paint;

  TouchPoints(this.points, this.paint);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing the code. I see you've removed the image, I've tried to use the image but the container is simply white. Tried with a white container to no avail. And you've also kept the onPanEnd empty? Can you kindly explain?

Comment: I've tried to use  the image on top of the stack and I can't color it.  here's the code: https://pastebin.com/YXt6ck35